# How can I derive from a class with a non-virtual destructor?

Tags: c++, polymorphism

I have the following problem. I would like to derive a class Derived from Base, but unfortunately Base has a non-virtual destructor (and I am not allowed to touch Base):

```
class Base{
public:
~Base(); //not virtual, cannot be changed
}

class Derived : public Base{
public:
~Derived();
// more stuff
}
```

The problem with this would be:

```
Base* tmp = new Derived();
delete tmp;
```

which would compile, but not call the right destructor. Thus my question:  How could I prevent a downcast of the derived pointer to the base class? Is there maybe another clever solution for this problem? Or is deriving from a class with non-virtual destructors just an absolute no-go?

Comment: If you used a smart pointer rather than a raw pointer, this would be ok.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth does that not depend on the type contained inside the smart pointer? if the type of the smart pointer is `Base` the problem is still the same, right?

Comment: The problem is not the derivation, the problem is the polymorphic usage. The answer is that you design your code around it. Don't delete something you did not allocate.

Comment: Does `Base` have any virtual functions? Otherwise no one would ever do `Base* tmp = new Derived();`.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth. The problem is not me making this mistake. It is other developers being unaware of this pitfall.

Comment: The simple answer is if there's a risk that people will get it wrong - then don't do it;  create a wrapping class instead

Comment: @TommyAndersen - Smart pointers are smart :)  See e.g. https://ideone.com/e34Pbn

Comment: I see :/  (FWIW, casting from derived to base is an *upcast*, not a *downcast*.)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth yes ok :) that was actually new to me, of course it only works if you pass the derived type to the constructor, and do not do something silly like storing it in a variable of type `Base` which you pass to the `shared_ptr` constructor.

Comment: Have you considered making `Derived` privately inherit from `Base`?

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth: I think it's only true for `shared_ptr`, but not `unique_ptr`, yeah?

Comment: I think you need to incapsulate `Base` type member into `Derived` class instead of direct derivation.